# The Meaning of Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm studying relations and I've been told that relations are sets of ordered pairs. My tutors provide examples like these:

The less than relation (<) consists of all ($a$,$b$) such that $b-a$ is a positive number so when we're taking about relations like (<), a question arises.

Is the relation between set(A) and (B) the set of all ordered pairs or is it the idea of the being less than itself?

Another example they provided:

People-to-pets relation they say it consists of all ordered pairs such that the first pair is people and the second pair is their pet and the same question arises:

Is the relation the set of all ordered pairs between the two sets or is it the idea of (owning) itself that tells us that people own pets?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the relation between set(A) and (B) is the set of all ordered pairs or It's the idea of the less than itself ?

According to mathematical theory of set, a *binary* [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) is a set of ordered pairs.

Consider for simplicity *natural* numbers, i.e. elements of the set $\mathbb N$; according to your tutor proposal, we define $< = \{ (n,m) \mid (m-n) \text { is positive } \}$.

Thus, the relation $<$ **is** a *set*: the set of ordered pair satisfying the formula in the definition, and we have that $< \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$.

Thus, $(1,2) \in <$ while $(1,1) \notin <$, and this "fits" with our usual usage of "less than".

The same for the "People-to-pets" relation: if Tom and Jerry are John's pets, then: $(\text {John, Tom}) \in \text {People-to-pets}$ and $(\text {John, Jerry}) \in \text {People-to-pets}$.

In this case we have: $\text {People-to-pets} \subseteq \text {People} \times \text {pets}$.

---

But we can approach relations also from other points of view; see [Relation algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_algebra).

Comment: So the realtion is mathematicaly defined as sets of ordered pairs and not the idea as i mentioned and i see it's a logical one because: if we define the realtion as the idea between the two pairs there can be pair (a,b) and carries no idea (you can't determine the type of realtion between the two pairs) so our definition can't hold here but if we define the realtion as sets of ordered pairs our definition will be completly valid. Am I right with my reasoning ?

Comment: @shehab - yes, the language of set theory provides a mathematical definition of *relation* that "fits" with our intuition. For *binary* relations: there is a first thing related to a second one, like a first number that is "less than" a second one or a first individual (a person) that "owns" a second one (a pet).