# What does it mean to say "the 'less than' relation on the set D is the set{(a, b): a, b $\in$D and a<b}"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein."

Section B.2 of the book gives an example of binary relation.

[image]

I'm aware that a function is a binary relation, for example the function f:A $\longrightarrow$ B defined by f(n)=2n describes the relation of the set A onto B.

However, I'm confused about the "less than" binary relation.

Consider the finite set D={0, 1, 2}, what does it mean to say "the 'less than' relation on the set D is the set{(a, b): a, b $\in$D and a<b}"

let a = 1, b = 2, how do I relate the ordered pair (a, b) = {a, {a, b}} = {1, {1, 2}} to 'less than' relation? what does 'less than' relation mean in this context?

Is it possible to relate the relation 'less than' to a real-life example?

For instance, I have a=1 apple my wife has b=2 apples, the relation between the two **numbers** conveys that I have less number of apples than my wife.

How do I relate the relation between two **sets**, e.g. the ordered pair (a, b) = {a, {a, b}} = {1, {1, 2}} to the number of apples?

I've read through some reference, e.g.
[https://eml.berkeley.edu/~dahn/201notes.pdf](https://eml.berkeley.edu/%7Edahn/201notes.pdf)

and the book is also available for free
https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf

Comment: Your example is too big to type. If $D = \{0,1,2,3\}$ then the relation "less than" is: $$<\; = \; \{(0,1),(0,2),(0,3), (1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}$$ and usually, instead of writing $(1,3) \in <$ we write $1 < 3$.

Comment: An important point in mathematics, not so much in computer science, is that a relation is an *arbitrary* subset of $A \times B$.  There is no requirement that this set of ordered pairs has a simple definition.  In this book, less than is the usual relation on the integers, the reals, or whatever.  Your paragraph after the picture, while correct, is probably too arbitrary for the subject at hand.  You can view a function as a restriction of a relation to those which have only one element for each first entry.  Computer scientists see a function as a bit of code which takes in

Comment: some inputs and returns a (or some) outputs.  This requires that a function be able to be described in a finite amount of code.  Math does not require that.  The context is important.  The picture you give is more mathematical than my image of computer science.  It supports the more arbitrary mathematical view, but the title of the book screams computer science.  You need to understand the context.

Comment: See [The Meaning of Relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433463/the-meaning-of-relations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a set-theorist, everything that exists is a set. So a binary relation $R$ on a set D must be defined as some set. It is customary to write $a<b$ to mean $a$ is less than $b.$ But a set-theorist will say that $<$ is some subset of $D\times D$ and that $a<b$ means $(a,b)\in <,$ which may look odd, as you may not be used to referring to $<$ as an object.

Similarly, a function IS its graph. And a binary operation on a set $D$ is a function from $D\times D$ to $D$. But even a set-theorist prefers to write $1+1=2$ rather than $((1,1),2)\in +.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $D = \{0,\ldots,9\}$ and look at $R = \{(a,b) \in D| a < b\}$. For example:

- $(0,i) \in R$ for any $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 9$
- $(-1,3) \not \in R$ since $-1 \not \in D$
- $(5,7) \in R$ but $(7,5) \not \in R$

The set $R$ then is exactly the relation $<$ on $D$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to relate the relation 'less than' to a real-life example?

For instance, I have a=1 apple my wife has b=2 apples, the relation between the two **numbers** conveys that I have less number of apples than my wife.

How do I relate the relation between two **sets**, e.g. the ordered pair (a, b) = {a, {a, b}} = {1, {1, 2}} to the number of apples?

Comment: @JJJohn - not very clear... Your concern is about the set-theoretic def of *ordered pair* $(a,b)$ as the set $\{ a, \{ a,b \} \}$?

Comment: If not, the issue is: $(1,2)$ is good for the set-theoretic def of $<$ because $1 < 2$ while $(1,1)$ is not. Thus, $(1,2) \in <$ and $(1,1) \notin <$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you so much. My concern is how do I relate $\{ a, \{ a,b \} \}$ to a real-life example, e.g. the numbers of apples my wife and I have respectively.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I guess the symbol $\{ a, \{ a,b \} \}$ is as simple as a set-theoretic notation indicating the order of the elements, since a typical set itself doesn't have order. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct; there is no "deep meaning" in the def; [there are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory). All boil down to find a "mechanism" to introduce order in a object (set) that has no order. A very intuitive one is the following: $(a, b) := \left\{ \{a, 1\}, \{b, 2\} \right\}$.